# AWS Polly v3: SynthesizeSpeech 'mp3', AudioStream not instanceOf Buffer

Tags: node.js, amazon-polly

I am converting **AWS Polly** code in Javascript (node) from **v2** to **v3**.

When using **AWS Polly v3** `synthesizeSpeech()`, how can I convert the returned `data.AudioStream` to an instance of `Buffer`?

The following JavaScript code works using **v2**, and returned `audio.AudioStream` is an instance of `Buffer`:

```
const { Polly } = require('aws-sdk');

// Create an Polly client
const polly = new Polly({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
});

const params = {
    OutputFormat: 'mp3',
    VoiceId: voiceId,
    TextType: 'ssml',
    Text: '<speak><prosody rate="85%">Hello World</prosody></speak>'
};

// ***

return await polly
    .synthesizeSpeech(params)
    .promise()
    .then(data => {
         if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
             return data.AudioStream
         } else {
             console.error('AudioStream not instanceof Buffer');
             return null;
         }
     })
```

The following JavaScript code using **v3**, its response from `synthesizeSpeech()` contains `audio.AudioStream` is not an instance of `Buffer`, but begins with `IncomingMessage`:

```
const {
    Polly
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-polly");

// Create an Polly client
const polly = new Polly({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
});

// ***

const params = {
    OutputFormat: 'mp3',
    VoiceId: voiceId,
    TextType: 'ssml',
    Text: '<speak><prosody rate="85%">Hello World</prosody></speak>'
};

return await polly
    .synthesizeSpeech(params)
    .then(data => {
         if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
             return data.AudioStream
         } else {
             console.error('AudioStream not instanceof Buffer');
             return null;
         }
     })
```

I have all tried the following **v3** using `PollyClient` and `SynthesizeSpeechCommand`, same results

```
const {
    PollyClient,
    SynthesizeSpeechCommand
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-polly");

const client = new PollyClient({
    region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
});

// ***

const command = new SynthesizeSpeechCommand({
    OutputFormat: 'mp3',
    Text:'hello world, this is alex',
    VoiceId: 'Kimberly',
    TextType: 'text'
});

return client
    .send(command)
    .then((data) => {
        if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
            return data.AudioStream
        } else {
            console.error('AudioStream not instanceof Buffer');
            console.log('data.AudioStream:', data.AudioStream);
            return null;
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Contents of **v3** `data.AudioStream` is:

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     ***
```

Thank you for reading, any feedback appreciated.

Comment: here rate="85%" is speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now is a ReadableStream object.

```js
   import { Readable } from "stream";
    //...
    if (data.AudioStream instanceof Readable) {
      console.log("Readable");
      data.AudioStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("fileName.mp3"));
    } else {
      console.log("no Readable");
    }
    //...
```

You can find details about this change here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1096#issuecomment-620900466

Comment: in my case, OutputFormat is pcm, i want to write file on disc in wav format. fs can't help in this? as this returns me Buffer, using wav library i can convert, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Personally i find it a lot easier using async/await instead of stream callbacks...

```
import { PollyClient, SynthesizeSpeechCommand, SynthesizeSpeechInput } from "@aws-sdk/client-polly";
import fs from 'fs';

async function go() {
    const client = new PollyClient(yourClientOptions)
    const command = new SynthesizeSpeechCommand(yourCommandOptions)
    try {
        let data = await client.send(command)
        if (!data || !data.AudioStream) throw Error(`bad response`);
        await saveStream(data.AudioStream, "output.mp3")
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

function saveStream(fromStream, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let toStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
        toStream.on('finish', resolve);
        toStream.on('error', reject);
        fromStream.pipe(toStream)
    })
}

go()
```

Note: I'm using node14 so can use `import` at the top, but you could just as easily use `require`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I ran into this and found this as a fix for it:

```
//old v2   
return HttpResponse.Ok({
   AudioStream: result.AudioStream! // buffer
});
     
//new v3
const byteArray = await result.AudioStream.transformToByteArray();
return HttpResponse.Ok({
    AudioStream: Buffer.from(byteArray) //buffer again
});
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to cache the bytearray in memory instead of saving the stream directly to file, which is a waste of memory