# NodeJS AWS Polly - returned audio file seems corrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

The returned and written .mp3 file is not playable and seems broken. I can not find any reason why, logging the audioBuffer looks fine.

```
const request: AWS.Polly.SynthesizeSpeechInput = {
    Text: textToSSMLResponse.ssml,
    TextType: 'ssml',
    OutputFormat: 'json',
    VoiceId: 'Matthew',
    Engine: "neural",
    SpeechMarkTypes: ["ssml"]
};

const response = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request).promise();
const data = response.$response.data as AWS.Polly.SynthesizeSpeechOutput;

const audioBuffer = data.AudioStream;

fs.writeFileSync(`src/tmp/filename.mp3`, audioBuffer, 'binary');
```

Logging the audioBuffer logs a Buffer:

```
Buffer 7b 22 74 69 6d 65 22 3a 37 30 33 37 2c 22 74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 73 73 6d 6c 22 2c 22 73 74 61 72 74 22 3a 31 35 34 2c 22 65 6e 64 22 3a 31 37 38 2c 22 ... 93 more bytes>
```

I do not see any reason why the file is not playable, there must be an issue in how I handle the returned AudioStream.

> audioBuffer is of type AWS.Polly.AudioStream which is defined as
>
> ```
> type AudioStream = Buffer|Uint8Array|Blob|string|Readable;
> ```

Comment: note that I have to use output format json in order to use the speech marks.

Comment: What version of node? `binary` encoding is deprecated.

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A which appears to be very similar to your Q, particularly the accepted answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959928

Answer (score 1):

Change `OutputFormat = "mp3"` instead of `OutputFormat = "json"`

```
    const { StartSpeechSynthesisTaskCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-polly");
const { pollyClient } = require("./libs/pollyClient.js");

// Create the parameters
var params = {
  OutputFormat: "mp3",
  OutputS3BucketName: "videoanalyzerbucket",
  Text: "Hello David, How are you?",
  TextType: "text",
  VoiceId: "Joanna",
  SampleRate: "22050",
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    await pollyClient.send(new StartSpeechSynthesisTaskCommand(params));
    console.log("Success, audio file added to " + params.OutputS3BucketName);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error putting object", err);
  }
};
run();
```

Comment: I have to use output format json in order to use speech markers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/using-speechmarks.html "Amazon Polly supports only the JSON format when returning speech marks."

Comment: @niclas_4 did you try using writeFile instead of writeFileSync. I am not sure how to read the stream in node js. In Python, we first read the contents from the stream and then save that content as mp3.